# Detecting a change in the active camera (front/rear)

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller

I have code that does different logic based on which camera is used such as:

```
if(aPickerInstance.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront){
   // Front camera logic
}else{
   // Rear camera logic
}
```

My issue is that when the switch occurs, front-to-rear or vice versa, I have found no way to tell when the "cameraDevice" property value has changed in order to reevaluate my states. (basically rerun logic blocks to set everything right for the newly selected camera).

Answer (score 0):

When you create your picker, add an observer:

```
[_picker addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"cameraDevice" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then add the handler:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Keypath %@ change %@", keyPath, change);
}
```

change[@"new"] will give you a new value for cameraDevice. You can also just use this to detect a change and trigger your own cameraDevice state check.

Comment: Took my time to try what you suggested and a few variants of the solution with no success. I haven't been able to recognize the change for some weird reason.

Comment: can you post code on when you create the aPickerInstance, and what controller is doing it?